# Preventing multiple appends to a file

Tags: bash, file, append

What is the best way to use bash scripting to check if one file has been appended multiple times to another? I need to do this without installing extra tools. I am updating a file periodically by appending another to it and want to make sure the action hasn't happened previously.

I have tried doing various diff's and wc solutions but cannot find a solution.

Comment: When you append, is it OK to insert a dividing line with information that can help you make that determination? How, specifically, have you tried (and failed) to check before?

Comment: diff  a.csv b.csv | sed -e '1d' -e 's/^..//g' | diff - a.csv | sed -e '1d' -e 's/^..//g' | diff - b.csv is one way.  
$1, $2 being parameters as files
L1=$(diff $1 $2 | sed -e '1d' -e 's/^..//g' | wc -l | awk '{print $1}')        
L2=$(wc -l $2 | awk '{print $1}') 
L3=$(wc -l $1 | awk '{print $1}')
    
if [ $(( $L1 + $L3 )) -ne $L2 ];
    then
        echo "Failed diff on $1"
 exit 1;
    fi
is another.
This file is read for other systems so adding a dividing line would be difficult. I apologize for my poor bash scripting skills

Comment: Please enclose code snippets in `\`` (backticks) - it makes them much easier to read. Your snippets look awfully complicated - generally speaking, would the following approach work? Extract as many lines from the end of the target file as the reference file has, then compare the extracted lines to the reference file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), one solution might be to `diff` the last lines from the target file with the source file, as many lines as there are in source. Here is a sketch:

```
#!/bin/bash
# USAGE: append_uniq.sh target source
# append source to target only if last part of target != source

target_file=$1
source_file=$2
source_num_lines=$(wc -l < "$source_file")
diff_target_lines=$(tail -n $source_num_lines "$target_file")

if ! diff "$source_file" <(echo "$diff_target_lines") > /dev/null; then
    echo "Appending $source_file to $target_file"
    cat "$source_file" >> "$target_file"
else
    echo "Already appended, skipping"
fi
```

**Bonus: one-liner**

Append file`a` to file `lines` unless `a` already last appended to `lines`. Both files must exists:

```
! diff -q a <(tail -n $(wc -l < a) lines) && cat a >> lines
```

Comment: Just a suggestion:  you might consider `$(wc -l <a)` as a replacement for the pipeline `$(wc -l a | cut -d' ' -f1)`

Comment: +1, but please double-quote all references to `$source_file` and `$target_file`.

Comment: I used
`DIFF=$(diff $1 $2)
 if [ -s $1 ] && [ -s $2 ] && [ "$DIFF" != "" ]; 
 then
     L1=$(diff $1 $2 | sed -e '1d' -e 's/^..//g' | diff - $2 | sed -e '1d' -e 's/^..//g' | grep -xc "-")
     if [[ $L1 -ne 1 ]];
         then
            echo "Failed diff on $1"
            exit 1;
        fi
    fi`